# How configure charles-proxy to work with chrome in linux

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, ubuntu-14.04, charles-proxy

I try setting the chrome proxy:

```
google-chrome --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8888
```

Chrome opens a new window, but charles does not capture any.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have the same issue, nothing shown in charles

Comment: Sorry, I have not found a solution for now :(

Comment: Probably, you need quotation marks: `google-chrome --proxy-server="127.0.0.1:8888"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Charles opens up a proxy usually at localhost:8888 (you can change it in the Proxy > Proxy settings... menu), so what you have to do is simply add this proxy server to your connections.

The best way to achieve that I've found is by installing the [Proxy SwitchyOmega extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif), configuring the proxy parameters as told before and **switching manually** whenever you want to track http requests.

It's not as easy as it is on windows but works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Lluis, works as you say, I used [SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif/related) extension (SwitchySharp currently is not maintained)