# Download dynamic image on webpage programmatically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to download an image which changes on every load.
The `src` attribute on the `img` tag is constant, though the image being displayed changes (I'm guessing the web app changes the image at `src` on every hit).

I did try downloading using `src`, and the image returned is different, as expected.

My requirement is to download the image that is displayed on the page, at the moment.
I also tried right click to save, but right click is disabled in the page.
Any ideas ?
I'm using selenium webdriver.Other options are also welcome.

This is what I tried using the `src` attribute :

```
public static void download() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://*******.com/");

    String url = driver.findElement(By.id("regImg")).getAttribute("src");

    // run of the mill code to download the image.
    downloadImage(url);
}
```

As I said, this code works, but I get a different image as the web app changes it on every hit. I need the one that is displayed on the page.

Here's the HTML:

```
<td width="20%" align="center" class="style1">characters
    <font color="#FF0000">*</font>
    <img id="regImg" src="../../**/**.php" alt="captcha image" height="25">
</td>
```

Comment: Add relevant HTML, or link and code you have so far

Comment: Please add a relevant HTML

Comment: You are looking in different part of the HTML then, try sharing the website or HTML

Comment: @Kushal I've verified that the `src` attribute doesn't change by manually reloading and inspecting the element a few times. I'm not in a position to disclose the website.

Comment: So if you manually extract "src"a ttribute from <img> then it is the same which you want?

Comment: You don't have to post the whole HTML, only a relevant block. It is not possible to help you in this case, if you won't post a HTML

Comment: @Kushal Yes. The image it points to changes though. I can paste the image url in my browser and refresh it over and over to receive different images.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able get the previous image, as image changes on every refresh as you said

Comment: @Kushal Any chance I can download the one displayed on the web page? I was thinking the browser cache or similar workaround ?

Comment: I think it is not possible as its location is different, so only solution i seems should take the screenshots

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the option to regenerate the same image e.g. by appending a request parameter in your test, you can take a screenshot

```
File sreenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

and extract the image from the screenshot, which should be easy if you know what you are looking for.

Alternatively as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24268915/1602555) you could configure Selenium driver to use a known directory to store the browser data with:

```
ChromeOptions chromeProfile = new ChromeOptions();
chromeProfile.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + chromeProfilePath);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

and perhaps the random image will be saved on the disk somewhere under `chromeProfilePath`. [It's possible but the process is complex](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/recovering-images-from-google-chrome-browser-cache).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if your images are loaded from the same URL as HTML or from another.

You can try to convert all images to data objects by JS:

```
driver.execute_script(
    'var c=document.createElement("canvas");'+
    'document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(img){'+
       'c.width=img.naturalWidth;'+
       'c.height=img.naturalHeight;'+
       'c.getContext("2d").drawImage(img,0,0);img.src=c.toDataURL();'+
     '});'
);
```

And then capture it with your downloadImage.

But if your images are hosted on another host - you will have problems with CORS. Those problems may be fixed by adding CORS header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

With Charly proxy as shown here: [Add header to requests with Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168074/add-header-to-requests-with-charles)